# dynamic graph using matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate():
    data = np.loadtxt("new.txt")
    ax1.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
    return

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=1000)
plt.show()
```

the error poping up is 
TypeError: animate() takes no argument(1 given)
what to do??

Comment: Remove brackets `()` from `animate` (I have never used it) but this is what the documentation says. and in fact both of the errors are some Name typo. ..

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two errors in your code:

1. The file you are trying to read does really not exist or is not readable by your script. (That is why you get the error message.)
2. As `Hima` correctly says, the `FuncAnimation` expects to receive a function (i.e. `animate`) whereas `animate()` is the return value of the function.

Then there is one thing you should consider. If your data is in a simple file, you might try using the `numpy.loadtxt` to read that file. In that case your function `animate` would be something like:

```
import numpy as np

def animate():
    data = np.loadtxt("myfile.txt")
    ax1.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

However, even after that you will end up with an increasing number of plots, because every `plot` command creates a new line. Instead you might want to have a look at the `set_xdata` method. (As I guess this is a school assignment, I won't give the full solution.)

Comment: one error is coming when i used this code, TypeError: animate() takes no arguments (1 given)...pls help me i have to submit it working by morning

Comment: PLease update the code in your question to be exactly what is giving you the errors. Make sure that you initiate the animation by `ani=animation.FuncAnimate(fig, animate, frames=1000)`

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import numpy as np


fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate():
    data = np.loadtxt("new.txt")
    ax1.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
    return

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=1000)
plt.show()